# Why are the left- and right-hand sides of a differential equation with two separated variables equal to a constant?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

While deriving the Time Independent Schrodinger Equation, my book mentioned this line.

[image: Text]

So time and position of a particle are two independent variables. If they are equal to one another for all values of $t$ & $r$, then why should they be equal to a constant?

Can't we have other solutions to this other than treating both the sides as a constant?

Comment: Have you taken a course on partial differential equations yet? This is explained in courses such as those

Comment: @Triatticus Actually no. My college is teaching me this stuff in the 1st semester itself. I have basic high school knowledge on Ordinary Differential Equations only.

Comment: @Triatticus Can you please please explain this or at least provide a link/name to what I should read to understand this?

Comment: Can you think of another way for two functions of independent variables to be equal for all values of those variables?

Comment: I would suggest learning about *separation of variables*, this should help.

Comment: @G.Smith Actually I don't fully understand this statement. Are we talking about two functions $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(t)=\sin t$ to be equal to corresponding values of x & t. For example the functions are equal at $x=2m$ and $t=2sec$. In fact they are equal to each other for all values of them.

Comment: Hint: consider the simplest case, $f(t)=g(r)$. Now choose any $r=r_0$, so $f(t)=g(r_0)$ for all $t$.

Comment: @PM2Ring: or choose any $t=t_0$, then $f(t_0)=g(r)$. $f(t_0)$ is by definition a number.

Comment: @G.Smith I think I get the flaw in my argument. Using my argument, the variables won't be independent. So that is why the two sides must equal a constant.

Comment: Excellent crash course on sep. of PDEs/eigenvalue problems here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeparationofVariables.aspx

Comment: @Gert Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Gert Do I need to know about the previous stuff in Paul's notes like Laplace Transforms and Fourier series before studying PDEs?

Comment: @harshit54: No, not really. FTs do pop up sometimes in PDE seps., to use the *initial condition*. But I'm not very good with FTs and had no problem following the method. It's kind of high school level.

Comment: Incidentally, the time independent SE is also solved (if possible) by sep. of variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two logical options when you vary $t$: either the value of the left-hand side changes, or it doesn't. If it changes, then the right side must change as well, since they are equal. But the right-hand side *can't* change when you vary $t$, since it is not a function of $t$! Therefore, since varying $t$ produces no change in the  left-hand-side, then the left-hand side must be constant. And since it is equal to the right-hand side, then they are both (the same) constant.

Comment: Well said.  +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also for this to be true, you assume that r and t are independent variables, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Can't we have other solutions to this other than treating both the
>   sides as a constant?

No. The TDSE (and many other similar PDEs, like the TISE, the Newtonian wave equation and Fourier's equation) has a numeric separation constant. They are known as *eigenvalue* problems.